# How to find an expression for $q(t)$ given the definition of $i$?

Tags: integration, physics

Say are given any funcition that describes i for an ideal circuit element.  How do I find the expression $q(t)$ to describe the amount of charge per unit of time?

The idea was to first derive $q(t)$ from the definition of charge, $i=dq/dt$.
to do this, I  integrate both sides with respect to $t$, to get...

$$i=\frac{dq}{dt}$$

$$\int_{0}^{t}i\, dq\, \; =\; \int_{0}^{t}dq$$
$$\int_{0}^{t}i(q)\, dq\, \; =\; q(t)$$

So, now in the problems I will be given a value for $i$ at $t=0$.
$i=5$, $i=20e{^{-5000t}}$, $i=20\, cos\, (5000t)$, etc. None of this is homework.

This is the part I'm not sure how to do.

For $i=5$, I could say$$\int_{0}^{t}5(q)\, dq\, \; =\; q(t)$$,
$$5t=q(t)$$

For $i=20e{^{-5000t}}$, I could say$$\int_{0}^{t}20e{^{-5000t}}(q)\, dq\, \; =\; q(t)$$,
$$t\,20e{^{-5000t}}=q(t)$$

In this case, I should get $4000\: \mu C$.  If anyone can help me with this one, I should be able to figure out the third case by myself. :)

Thanks so much.

For those curious, this example is on page 38 of Electric Circuits, Nilsson [10th]

[image: figure 1.5]
[image: textbook assessment problem]

Comment: Since the question asked for 'total' charge, should I be finding $$\lim_{t->\infty}\int_{0}^{t}$$ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> For $i=20e{^{-5000t}}$, I could say$$\int_{0}^{t}20e{^{-5000t}}(q)\, dq\, \; =\; q(t)$$,
>   $$t\,20e{^{-5000t}}=q(t)$$

**No, you have to respect the rules for integrals:**
$$q(t)=\int_{0}^{t}20e{^{-5000t'/\text{s}}}\text{A}\, dt'\, \; =\; \left[\frac{20\text{s}}{-5000}\cdot e{^{-5000t'}}\right]^t_0 \; {= \; \left[-0.004\cdot e{^{-5000t'}}\text{A}\text{s}\right]^t_0 }{= 0.004\cdot(1-e{^{-5000t}})\ \text{A}\text{s},} $$
which gives you $0.004C = 4000\mu C$ for $t \to \infty$.

**For clarity since asked in the comments:**

**Why $q(t)=\int_{0}^{t}20e{^{-5000t'/\text{s}}}\text{A}\, dt'$?**
$$q(t)= \int_0^ti(t')dt',$$
because the total charge is the time integral over the current during the observed time period.

**Why not $q(t)=\int_{0}^{t}20e{^{-5000'/\text{s}}}\text{A}\, dt$?**
It has a different meaning (and is somewhat not well defined).
I just [answered it here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1433087/261163) because this is another question.

**Why not something like $r$ instead of $t'$?**
In physics, we tend to use as similar symbol as possible, so $t'$ is a good call.
This way is stays clear this means **time**.
**You are right, it often means a space derivative**, so using $\tilde{t}$ would be a somehow better option.
But you can also expect this not meaning a derivative, since you are looking at electrics here.
I'm going to let it stay since you asked and this and are surely not the only one confused by this.
In calculus (in math), you can use any unused variable, since you only care about the integral and not a specific use or meaning.

**Why not $q(t)=\int_{0}^{t}20e{^{-5000t'/}}\, dt'$?**
A (Ampére) and s (second) since you should always care about having the right dimensions.
[There can happen bad things if dimensions are not clear for everyone using the same units/system.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mars_Climate_Orbiter#Cause_of_failure)
Especially as a beginner, be careful.
(And as a veteran you habe possibly made enough errors because of this to stay careful. :D)

Comment: I dont know how you got $$q(t)=\int_{0}^{t}20e{^{-5000t'/\text{s}}}\text{A}\, dt'$$, specifically what $dt'$ and $t'/s$ mean.

Comment: @LetThisNightExplode $t^{\prime}$ is just another variable. Notice that with integration, it doesn't matter what variable is after the $\text{d}$, e.g., $\text{d}x$, $\text{d}y$,... as long as whatever is inside the integral is consistent with the variable. Notice here that $t$ is in the integration limits. In general, it's considered poor notation to use the same variable in one of the integration limits and as the $\text{d}$ variable.

Comment: Interesting.  I thought that $'$, as 'prime' meant derivative in (newtons?) notation. where $x'$ would be equivalent to saying $dx$.  So I thought there was a blending of notations.  Could I just use another letter, like $x$ instead of $t'$? Why do you need to introduce a new variable when there are only 3 ($i$, $q$, and $t$) in the original equation?