# Why to use dummy variables in definite integrals?

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, change-of-variable

I'm interested in knowing what is the utility of using [dummy variables](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/DummyVariable.html) in definite integrals; that is, why use $\int_0^xf(x')dx'$ instead of $\int_0^xf(x)dx$.

In case they have no real utility and it is only a convention used for historical reasons, it would be interesting to know what were the reasons that originally led to the introduction of this concept.

Note: I have seen this question or a similar one posted [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/940640/why-do-we-use-dummy-variables-in-integrals), but I'm not sure the OP was asking the question in the sense I ask, and I don't think any of the answers given explains the matter...

Comment: $\int_0^x f(x)\ dx$ is technically abuse of notation. The $x$ in the limit is a fixed number. But the $x$ in the $f(x)\ dx$ part is completely different, it varies between $0$ and previous $x$, which is already confusing to think about. It is like using the number $3$ as the number itself and a variable at the same time.

Comment: Some people get confused when the variable of integration is the same as the upper limit.  I agree with you; they mean different things and there should be no confusion, but lots and lots of people disagree with me.  Since many people find it confusing, it's best to go with the flow.  After all, you're writing to communicate with the reader, not to display your erudition, although many mathematical writings seem to contradict this.

Comment: Now it is clear to me, thank you, you have explained exactly the doubt I had :)

Comment: @saulspatz I don't think it's a benign abuse of notation at all. We may want to consider a family of functions indexed by some parameter, and looking at integrals where that parameter appears both in the function being integrated and as one of the bounds - e.g. $$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\int_1^nx^{-n}dx.$$ This makes it absolutely crucial that we not reuse variables that way.

Comment: @NoahSchweber I don't think that the same at all.  There's only one variable $n$ and it's bound by the limit.  In the original expression, I would say that only the $x$'s in the integrand are bound by the $dx$, and the limit of integration is a free variable.  We'll have to agree to disagree.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a matter of correctness and to ease readability. In fact the term *bound* variable is much more appropriate than the term *dummy* variable since it  addresses the *scope* of variables which is relevant here.

A discrete pendant might help to better see the situation:

Consider the formulas
\begin{align*}
\sum_{k=1}^n k=\frac{n(n+1)}{2}\qquad\qquad\qquad \sum_{k=1}^k k\stackrel{???}{=}\frac{k(k+1)}{2}
\end{align*}

The index $k$ in the left sum is a *bound* variable with scope given by the sigma symbol. The variable $n$ on the other hand is a *free* variable whose existence is not bound by the sigma symbol. The right sum is nonsense. *[Free and bound variables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_variables_and_bound_variables#Examples)* are the main theme here and also in OPs example.