# What is the meaning of the apostrophe?

Tags: calculus, notation, terminology, mathematical-physics

I have come across this a few times

$$\Pr(x<X)= \int_{-\infty}^x \mathrm dx' f(x')$$

This is clearly just the integral of the PDF up to the value $x,$ but there must be some very powerful reason to use that apostrophe that trump the ambiguity it introduces with the common uses of an apostrophe: derivative and transposed.

Comment: It is just some notation. You can change $x'$ for $y$ if you wish.

Comment: It's just to signify another variable. You could call it $y$ if you wanted. Sometimes authors will do this because $x$ has special meaning, e.g. as a position variable in quantum mechanics.

Comment: I bet it was used as notation of dummy variable in order to not mess up with $x$ in integration bound (not the best choice, in my opinion).

Comment: I would agree with you, why not use p say.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The expression $x'$ (read as '$x$ prime') is commonly used to denote 'an independent variable which is like $x$ but a bit different in some way'. It is just a name for a variable. Similarly, $\tilde{x}, \hat{x}, \check{x}, \ldots$ are often used. It is unfortunate that it is also used to denote e.g. the derivative of the object $x$ thought of as a function of some other variable.

In this case, the idea is $x \in \mathbb{R}$ is what you want to call the variable running over the range of possible values $X$ can take; but because you need such a variable to appear both as the argument of the CDF **and** as the integration variable when integrating the PDF, we need two *different* '$x$-like variables'. So one is called $x$ and one is called $x'$. This is a common notation for dummy variables in integrations like this. But call it $\hat{x}$ or $y$ or $\xi$ or whatever you fancy.

Since you ask for the "powerful reason" for doing this -- I'm not sure whether this counts as powerful, but the benefit here is that **you always know what '$x$-like' variables are indexing**, namely potential values of the random variable.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Since the domain of the CDF and the PDF, wouldn't the variable be exactly the same, i.e. domain of the random variable? I would see the need of this split in obtaining a Fourier transform: time in the base function; frequency in the transform.

Comment: BTW, "powerful reason" is a totally facetious and sarcastic way of refraining from using expletives... Sometimes it truly feels like the cognoscenti relish the aura of obscurantism in unexplained and unmotivated notation. :-)

Comment: @Math tourist: The variables are indeed both indexing values of the random variable, which is why it is desirable to have similar notation for both, but you cannot use the same name as they appear in the same expression whilst taking different values. You should not write $\int_0^x 2x dx = x^2$ as the symbol $x$ is ambiguous on the left hand side! For example, changing the name of the dummy variable, I could equally well have meant to communicate $\int_0^x 2x dy = 2x^2$.

Comment: I would not be able to understand how the very last expression in your last comment could possibly be true.

Comment: See also e.g. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3925281/why-to-use-dummy-variables-in-definite-integrals

Comment: If you compute $\int_0^a a^2 b^7 db = a^2 \int_0^a b^7 db = \frac 1 8 a^{10} $ it's clear what is going on - I integrate a function of b over b, then substitute in $b=a$ at the upper limit. If I instead decide that I want to call my integration variable $a$ as well, then I'm going to get very confused as soon as I write down $\int_0^a a^2 a^7 da$, aren't I? Do I mean I want to integrate $\int a^9 da$? Or do I mean $a^2 \int a^7 da$? Or maybe even $a^7\int a^2 da$? Or $a^9 \int 1 da$?